# AWS Lambda list function with error in last x minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to have an overview about all lambdas that have failed in a given timeframe. I know that I can see the status (including errors) of a lambda when I navigate to its detail page on AWS console, but since we have a large number of lambda functions, it is not feasible to go through every function one by one to get an overview of which lambdas are failing.

Is there any way to get such an overview?

Comment: You need to study how to query CloudWatch. This information is there. I dont have an example ready, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I tried cloudwatch Insights feature. However, I can only query a maximum of 20 lambdas with that feature. I couldn't find a way to query the logs of all lambdas unfortunately.

Comment: Share what you have tried so far... i've tried something with aws cli but it seems to be very complex for such a simple task